# Property binding to a Child UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I've got a problem I couldn't get solved until now:
I am developing an application in C#/WPF and am using the Caliburn.micro as framework. I have multiple menu panels (as user controls) that I want to reuse all over the application (e.g. data filtering menu for a grid) and show in a `<ContentControl />`. Depending on the state of the application a different menu panel can be shown.

Now I could get managed to let events bubble up from the menu's View to the parent's ViewModel. But I'm stuck with properties:
For example in the filtering menu, one should enter a text while the filter is instantly applied. When I had the menu in the parent's View it was easy: I just made the filtering in the property's setter method.

Is there a possibility to make a kind of "property-bubbling" similar to the message bubbling in c.m (it has to be twoWay!)? Or any other (better) MVVM-compliant approach?

Thanks in advance!

Jan

---

Minimal example:

ParentView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.ParentView">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="Toolbar" />
    </Grid> 
</UserControl>
```

ParentViewModel.cs

```
class ParentViewModel : Screen
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        Toolbar = new MenuViewModel();
    }

    private Screen _toolbar;
    public Screen Toolbar
    {
        // get, set ...
    }

    public void LoadDifferentMenu()
    {
        this.Toolbar = new DifferentMenuViewModel();
    }
}
```

MenuView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.MenuView">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="MyText" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MenuViewModel.cs

```
class MenuViewModel : Screen
{
    public MenuViewModel()
    {   
    }

    private string _myText;
    public string MyText
    {
        // get, set...
    }
}
```

Comment: If the TextBox is databound to some property of the view model, then it's not that different from events - you may just react on PropertyChanged event (or what have you) and relay the info, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Event Aggregator` in caliburn micro to implement publisher and subscriber pattern in MVVM.

Communication is based on message type so it can be used for one way or two way communication with appropriate types.

Kindly refer to the link https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator for implementation details.

Comment: Ok, but if I got it right, an event is an unidirectional way of communication. So if I want to clear the textbox for example, I have to add more logic to the submenu's VM. Isn't there a way to get this two-way "binding" out of the box?